# Thymeleaf support in InteliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I'm working with a legacy spring boot application with InteliJ IDEA.

The project uses Thymeleaf templates.

I'm able to get some IDE support for Thymeleaf syntax, but it's very rudimentary.

It will do basic auto-completion for th:* attributes, but some syntax it doesn't understand at all.

For example, I've got this style block in a template...

```
<style th:inline="text">
    #Home {
        background-image: url([[${@environment.getProperty('myStaticAddress') + '/images/my_background_image.jpg'}]]);
    }
</style>
```

This renders correctly. However the IDE has no clue what this is, and just underlines it as a css error.

Is there some way to enable more complete support for Thymeleaf in IDEA?

I'm not very familiar with Thymeleaf, so this lack of IDE support really slows things down.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Ultimate version of IntelliJ IDEA, then you can see what is supported at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/thymeleaf.html

There are quite some requests to improve Thymeleaf support at their bugtracker as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BLang.%20Thymeleaf%7D%20%23Open%20%23Reopened%20%23Submitted%20